# Find out if app was already initialized?

Tags: python, pyside, qapplication

I wanted to spawn a QWebKit instance in PySide and quickly got a segmentation fault - I forgot to set up an instance of QApplication. Since SIGSEGV is not a good failure mode, is there a way to catch that and throw an exception instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `QCoreApplication` class (which `QApplication` inherits), has the static method [instance()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#instance) which allows you to check this:

```
if QApplication.instance() is not None:
    # do stuff..
else:
    raise RuntimeError('no application object')
```